# Anatomy of a Female Giant

Tags: mythical-creatures, anatomy, reproduction

In many depictions of giants in fantasy, we usually get visual examples of the male of the species, especially in more realistic settings in terms of biology (Game of Thrones Wun-Wun etc.)  But as far as I know we don't of a depiction of what a female giant would look like as well as some issues in giant anatomy that I'm honestly surprised no has asked before.  Live birth.

Being a bipedal, 3 meter tall humanoid would most likely bring complications during child.  Would they need to lay down or stand up when giving birth?  Would there size mean that the head to hip ratio is lower in giants and thus have smaller hips and easier births than humans?  And it would seem logical that in order to lower body mass on the upper body, breasts would not be as accented as a humans and be closer to our ape cousins.

Some questions that have been plaguing me for sometime when it came to giant biology.  Now of course the next question may ask how does *mating* work.

Comment: Well, you see, the stamen meets the pistil...

Comment: I believe those are for flowers.  Though how giant sentient flowers reproduce would be an interesting thought experiment...

Comment: Well, you see, when a male and a female giant love each other very very much... His ***** enters her ****** and after enough stimulation, the variations in the levels of adrenaline and acetylcholine result in what's known as an orgasm. Sperm is released into the female, it meets and fuses with an egg cell, a zygote is formed and if pregnancy is successful a baby is born. Reproduction apart, both males and females will need strong bones and muscles in order to sustain their own weight, and some modifications to reduce said weight might indeed happen.

Comment: (1) The shape of human female breasts is purely decorative. It does not serve any functional purpose. Which is to say, it is under sexual selection: we don't know what male giants find attractive. For example, the ancient Romans found small breasts attractive. (Or at least that's what they wanted us to think.) (2) There is ample space for variation in the humanoid body plan; for example, gorillas are just about as tall as humans, but twice as heavy. Your humanoids could be tall and skinny, or tall and heavy; we cannot know. (3) 6 tonne, 4 meters tall elephants can mate successfully...

Comment: Seraphim don't you mean wider hips? Smaller hips generally give more complications. I would think wider more stocky at the hips would benefit much more as well. Supporting more of the weight without breaking is important. If it's wide enough it also doesn't need to deform during birth, which seems more beneficial the larger the creature becomes.

Comment: Human infants have an abnormally large head to body ratio and that's what makes birth so difficult for humans (compared to other animals). Interestingly, while a giant would need bigger bones, muscles, and just about everything else, they wouldn't need a bigger brain. With a smaller head proportionally, giants could conceivably have a much easier time giving birth than humans.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Female giants are built like male giants, because giant babies are not giant.**

Giants are a *homo* species.  They are not that distant from we sapiens.  The difference is that giants keep growing and growing.  And growing.  They are long lived and as opposed to growing for their first 16 years they grow for the first 30 years or more.

Adult giants have massively fat bodies and strong muscular arms and legs.   But a giant baby is the same size as a human baby.  This means that given the very large pelvis that giants wind up growing before they are sexually mature, there is no benefit to the female pelvis being shaped differently from that of a male.

Giants are so big because their shape approaches that of a sphere, to conserve heat (especially in the water).  Protuberances are reduced.  Females have minimal breasts.  Their heads only a little larger than human heads and their genitals are smaller than ours.   It is in fact difficult to tell a female giant from a male giant.  The giants themselves have funny stories about exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

Most examples I can think of for giant women in popular culture are highly sexualized, such as the [Amazonians](https://futurama.fandom.com/wiki/Amazonian) from Futurama, or [Diane](https://nanatsu-no-taizai.fandom.com/wiki/Diane) from Seven Deadly Sins. Practically I suppose it would depend on the intelligence and the time it takes for a giant to develop out side of the womb. Humans have trouble birthing due to the large size of our [heads](http://www.bbc.com/earth/story/20161221-the-real-reasons-why-childbirth-is-so-painful-and-dangerous). If giants had smaller heads and grew mostly outside of the womb birth may not be such a huge issue for them.